# Datawarehouse design for searching (and not analytics)

Tags: database-design, query-performance

I'm looking for input on data warehouse designed focused on querying/searching and not analytics. Eg. aggregations especially on time are not a concern or point of interest. Really about searching the data. Scale is small so dedicated products like elastic seem overkill (and would need to be supported by corporate IT which is a hurdle itself).

The core data is in a normalized "OLTP" type relational database. it consists of a core "product definition", then "lots/batches" for the products and finally "measurement data" for each of the batches. the measurement data is diverse and new ones get added regularly. Also a batch can be measured multiple times for each type of measurement. eg in the hierarchy it's 1:n for product-batches and 1:n for batches to each measurement table (tens of them, certainly less than 100 for now).

We already have a 3rd party application built on this OLTP database but it's kinda slow. The end-user can select as many of these measurements as he has interest in and sort on any of them resulting in large amounts of joins with filtering and sorting which I assume makes it slow also due to the impossibility to create optimal indexes.

How should we structure the database for best search performance? It's important to not loose/aggregate the individual measurements. or should we simply bite the bullet and use elastic anyway (and thereby rebuild the existing sql based tool from scratch)?

Comment: **ElasticSearch** is a good tool for *parsing* and searching large amounts of unstructured text for specific keywords within that text, for example an email that financial traders send out with stock prices mixed in with other random junk in the body of the email, and you wanted the ability to *parse* out the specific stock `ticker` and `price` from the body, without the other junk. If your use case is similar to this, then **ElasticSearch** will probably fit your needs well. But it sounds like your data is structured and simple, so a regular **RDBMS** may continue to make sense for this...

Comment: ... We'd need you provide specific information to be able to guide you on the best way to optimize your database and application performance though, inclusive of: which database system you're using and it's version, the schema of your tables with some sample data, and some examples of the queries your application runs that need performance tuning (and their current **execution plans** would be very helpful too). Without most of this information, your question is too generic and impossible to helpfully answer, unfortunately.

Comment: In regards to Elastic, we would not need the advanced text features. A PostgreSQL full text index would suffice. It's more about speed/latency. Currently an old oracle version is used but we will move to PostgreSQL and hence once you have funding would be good to think about optimizing the db design. Do we need to separate the "OLAP" part from the search part? Currently everything happens on the same data (note number of requests is not an issue).  I can't provide and of the queries/explain plans as as said the app is 3rd part and I'm not the dba. More a high level question really about design

Comment: When you said "*OLAP*", I think you meant *OLTP*, as your original post mentions, which in that case we couldn't advise you without the information I requested, because it strongly depends on that information. Unfortunately the only answer for high level design question is "*it depends*", because the specifics I requested can strongly influence that design. In some cases it makes sense to split OLAP from OLTP, other times it doesn't. Unfortunately it's not possible to advise any more specifically than that, without details. Despite being a 3rd party app, you should be able to still see what...

Comment: ...queries it's running (there are **profiler tools** available for different database systems), in which case you'd have access to their **execution plans**, and you should have access to the database itself so you should be able to provide information on the schema and sample data (even if both are anonymized it's still helpful). In any case, if it's a 3rd party system, then it sounds like your ability to improve it's performance is limited anyway and you'd need to work with the Vendor of that system so that they can improve their system's performance.